# Как правильно: 273 члена или 273 членов?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, счетный-оборот

Нужно определить, как правильно ответить.

Comment: Необходимо видеть полную фразу, чтобы правильно ответить.

Answer (score 2):

Полагаю, что это дело нужно размыслить следующим образом: если есть, то членА!
Если же нет, то "ОВ".

Answer (score 1):

Начальная информация:
**273** — это составное количественное числительное, которое отображается на письме несколькими отдельными словами: *двести семьдесят три* (а также *пятьсот восемьдесят три, девятьсот девяносто три, тысяча шестьдесят три*);
**273 члена** ([счетный оборот](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/587/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5)) — это словосочетание, образованное количественным числительным и существительным в форме родительного падежа.

В отсутствие контекста просто склоняем:
И. п. — двести семьдесят три члена;
Р. п. — двухсот семидесяти трёх членов;
Д. п. — двумстам семидесяти трём членам;
В. п. — двести семьдесят три члена;
Т. п. — двумястами семьюдесятью тремя членами;
П. п. — о двухстах семидесяти трёх членах.

Итожим:
счетный оборот, содержащий составное числительное, оканчивающееся на *два, три, четыре*, при склонении **всегда** имеет форму винительного падежа, совпадающую с формой именительного падежа (ср.: *надо избрать двадцать два — три — четыре представителя*).
Такая форма не зависит от одушевленности или неодушевленности значения слова ["член"](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD), которую вы, возможно подразумеваете:
вижу (В. п.) — *273 члена, 273 лица, 273 рубля, 33 богатыря, 463 ученика*.

[Синтаксические особенности количественных числительных](https://studfile.net/preview/985091/page:71/)